# XML android webview with collapsingtoolbarlayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-webview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Is there a way to make a webview with a collapsing search bar like chrome browser? I have tried using the coordinate layout and having a nestedscrollview around a webview, but the issue with that is the height becomes infinite and there is supposedly no way to fix it. I did a lot of research on how to do this but all I can find is using the nestedscrollview. Does anyone know how to ether fix that bug or have an example on how to make a webview with a collapsing searchbar/toolbar?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_design_support_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="60dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="255dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Example image of what I want, but with a webview.
[image]

Comment: is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985592/search-edittext-animation-like-chrome-app

Comment: Just added an image to the post. @FirozMemon

Comment: This github project might help you: https://github.com/takahirom/webview-in-coordinatorlayout

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I'm looking for however do you know why the statusbar is showing the text behind it in the gif?

Comment: I don't have any idea about it buddy, you might have to consult the owner of the project about it.